# django joining auth_user with extended user profile

Tags: python, mysql, django

In Django 1.6 I extended the django user model with my own model like

```
class Employee(models.Model):
   user        = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='profile')
   adress      = models.CharField(max_length=500)
   department  = models.ForeignKey(Department)

class Department(models.Model):
   name    = models.CharField('Name', max_length=200)
```

I now want the logged in user to view its data, and so I need to display all the related information from the tables employee, department and auth_user.

Normally I would use

```
    #employee = Employee.objects.select_related('department').select_related('user').get(user_id=request.user.id)
```

To hit all the tables I want. But for some reason, if I choose Employee.objects for my query I just get the information of the employee table joined with the department table, without the information of auth_user.
Is I start the query with User.objects... it is exactly the other way round. I can access the user_auth information but not the employee or department information.

I also tried the OneToOne relationship in my models, but with the same result. I'm pretty sure, that there is a simple way of joining app-tables with django-tables if they are referenced by foreign key relationships.

For completeness the difference between employee.id and employee.user_id

```
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   CONSTRAINT `department_id` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `polls_department` (`id`),
   CONSTRAINT `user_id` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `auth_user` (`id`)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not define your `Employee` model as a subclass of `django.contrib.auth.AbstractUser` ([docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-django-s-default-user))? You'll have access to all `User` related fields as well as the extra fields you have defined in your `Employee`class in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model to extend the user model.
Finally I ended up using your suggestion.